# pip install cx_Freeze does not work

Tags: python, macos, cx-freeze

I'm following these instructions for setting up cx_Freeze on Mac OS X in the Terminal: http://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/cx-freeze-and-pyside-on-mac/

When I type: `pip install cx_Freeze`

I just get a wall of output ending with:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of OS X, GCC, and Python are you using?

Comment: OS X 10.10.5, Python 3.4, and GCC version: `Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix`